# CSS: Make Absolute item in Overflow-Y always fill 100% of Scroll Height

Tags: css

I wanna make this absolutely positioned bar fill 100% of this overflow-y container's scroll height & change dynamically (if possible).

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="item"></div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
}

#item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/springer268/pen/oNZJrjN

// sidenote
Hacky solutions that don't work in my use case include making it position fixed, or making it absolute to another div above. It has to be relative to this container (zooming issues + other thing.) and actually change height. I'd really like to avoid JS here (using React & it'd get all funky).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a `#container-inner` element and place the content within that.

Or is this the solution you're referring to as "hacky"?

```css
#container {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #333;
}

#container-inner {
  position: relative;
}

#item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="container-inner">
    <div id="item"></div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works! Different from my other hacky solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an absolute element, you can do this :

```
body{
    background-color: #333;
}

#container {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
  border-left:2px solid lightgreen;
  margin-left : 50px;
}
```